# Django templating: I need to display only 5 'news-items', and add on 5 more items when I click on the show more button?

Tags: jquery, html, django

In my HTML file, I'm using **Django** to display only 5 items (and I'm not sure why it is not working). And my **jQuery** code should allow to append 5 more *'.news-item's.* I could use a second pair of eyes to figure out why my code isn't working?

### HTML:

```
{% block page-title %}News &amp; Announcements{% endblock %}

{% block main-content %}

<div class="news-page">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <h2 class="section-header">                                                                                        
      News &amp; Announcements                                                                                         
    </h2>

    {% if content.0 %}
    <!-- NEWS SEGMENT -->
    {% for content_item in content %}
    {% if forloop.counter > 5 %}
    <div class="news-item hidden">
      <div class="publish-date">{{ content_item.publish_date|date:"F j, Y, f A" }} UTC</div>
      {% if content_item.image %}
      <div class="img-container{% if content_item.link or content_item.message%}-small{% endif %}">
        <img src="{{ content_item.image }}">
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="news-content">
        {% if content_item.message %}
        <p>{{ content_item.message }}</p>
        {% endif %}
          {% if content_item.link %}
        <div class="content-link-title"><a href="{{ content_item.link }}">{{ content_item.link_title }}</a></div>
        <p class="content-paragraph">{{ content_item.link_summary }}</p>
        <a class="news-link" href="{{ content_itemlink }}">Link <img src="{{ base_link }}/static/images/desktop/chevro\
n_link10x18.png" ></a>
        <button class="btn show-more">Show 5 More</button>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-info no-content-alert" role="alert">No news or announcements at this time</div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

  {% block scripts %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ base_link }}/static/desktop/js/show-more.js"></script>
  {% endblock %}
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.show-more').hide();                                                                                                     
$('.show-more').click(function () {
    console.log('The button is clicked');
  $('.news-item:hidden:It(5)').show();                                                                                    
});
});
```

Comment: Can you output the html generated from the template

Comment: You should really change your code to provide a [mininal example](http://sscce.org)